# A union of finitely many closed convex sets is not necessarily locally star-shaped?

Tags: geometry, examples-counterexamples, convex-geometry

A subspace $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be *star-shaped* if there is a point $x_0\in X$ such that for each $x\in X$, the line segment from $x_0$ to $x$ lines in $X$. A subspace $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be *locally star-shaped* if every point of $X$ has a star-shaped neighbourhood in $X$. 
In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929340/a-question-regarding-ch-1-exercise-in-hatcher-algebraic-topology), the original poster claims that

> A union of finitely many closed convex sets is not guaranteed to be a locally star-shaped set.

Could anyone give an example of a union of finitely many closed convex sets which is not locally star-shaped?

**Edit**:

The definitions are taken from A. Hatcher's algebraic topology, page 38:
[image]

If we can prove that a union of finitely many closed convex sets is necessarily locally star-shaped, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929340/a-question-regarding-ch-1-exercise-in-hatcher-algebraic-topology) would not make much sense.

Comment: Do you mean "subset" wherever you write "subspace"?

Comment: @Evgeny, I was copying the definition from A. Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and the author uses the term "subspace".

Comment: What do you mean by neighborhood in $X$? An relative open subset of $X$?

Comment: @user251257, $N$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ if there exists an open set $U$ with $x\in U\subset N$.

Comment: @Zuriel Weird, because with that definition it appears to be true.

Comment: $U$ is relative open in $X$ right? Not open in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Does $U$ have to be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or just open in the inherited topology on $X$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, it is possible that the quote from the op of another question is a false statement.

Comment: @user251257, I think $U$ is relative open in $X$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, I am quoting definition from A. Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (page 38) and am not very sure what convention the author uses here.

Comment: I know  this is an old question but I wanted to add that here the word "neighborhood" is misleading. No neighborhood of the boundary would be contained in the set. Perhaps Hatcher should rephrase it as "every point of X has a star-shaped subset of X".

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_i$ be the finitely many closed and convex sets. $\forall x\in \bigcup_i F_i$, if $x$ is not in some of the $F_{j_k}$, then for each $k$, since $F_{j_k}$ is closed, take an open ball $B_k$ centered on $x$, disjoint from $F_{j_k}$. Let $B$ be the intersection of these finitely many open balls. It's still an open ball centered on $x$, and disjoint from all $F_{j_k}$.

Now, $B$ is star-shaped around $x$, as well as each $F_i$ where $i\neq j_k$ (since $x\in F_i$, and $F_i$ is convex), and so $B\cap F_i$ is star-shaped around $x$. Then,
$$B\cap(\bigcup_i F_i) = B\cap(\bigcup_{i\neq j_k} F_i) = \bigcup_{i\neq j_k} (B\cap F_i) $$
is a neighborhood of $x$ in $\bigcup_i F_i$, and it's a union of star-shaped sets around $x$, so it's star-shaped itself.

So $\bigcup_i F_i$ is locally star-shaped.

Thus the claim in your question is wrong.

Comment: Is is possible to always find such an open ball $B_k \subseteq \overline{F_{j_k}}$? What if we have one of the closed convex sets being a line segment in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Joppy by definition of openness in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is possible.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate You may want not to use $\overline A$ for $\Bbb R^n\setminus A$, because in topology that notation is more often used for the topological closure.

Answer (score 1):

The statement seems very much true to me. After a quick search in the pdf, Hatcher himself never seems to claim otherwise.

> **Note:** Defining locally star-shaped as: "for all $x\in S$ there is a neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $U_x$ is star-shaped and $U_x\subseteq S$" makes no sense, in my opinion. Since $\Bbb R^n$ is locally convex, it is apparent that said definition co-implies being a non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. So, I'll assume, as it looks, that the definition talks about relative neighbourhoods.

Let $C_1,\cdots, C_n$ be said closed convex subsets and $C=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$. Suppose the ones that contain $x$ are $C_1,\cdots, C_m$ and the ones which do not contain it are $C_{m+1},\cdots, C_n$. If $S=\bigcup_{i=m+1}^nC_{i}\ne\emptyset$, by closedness $d(x,S)>d>0$. Thus, if we consider the relative neighbourhood $B(x,d/2)\cap C$, it holds $$B(x,d)\cap C\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m C_i.$$

That set is star-shaped in $x$: consider $y\in B(x,d)\cap C$. Then, $y\in C_j$ for some $1\le j\le m$. Since $C_j$ is convex and $x,y\in C_j$ by hypothesis, the entire segment joining them is in $C_j$, hence in $C$.

Comment: Is a singleton considered a convex set? Then what about finite union of points? Is that locally star-shaped? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A finite union of closed convex sets $X=X_1\cup...\cup X_n$ is always locally star-shaped. For $x_0\in X$ let $\alpha$ denote the set of $k=1,...,n$ such that $x_0 \notin X_k$ and pick for each such $k$ an open ball $B_k$ centered at $x_0$ and disjoint from $X_k$. Then $$X \cap \bigcap_{k\in \alpha} B_k$$ is a star-shaped neighborhood at $x_0$.

I think the following provides an example of the claim in the case of non-closed sets: It suffices to construct a (non-closed) convex set $C$ with a boundary point $x_0$ such that $C\cup \{x_0\}$ is not locally star-shaped at $x_0$.

You may do this in the following way: Let $C_0$ be the open cone:

$$ C_0 = \{ (x,y,z) : 0<z<1,  x^2+y^2<z^2 \}$$
To this we now add some decorations (a collection of external line segments) on the cone:
$$ C_1 = \{ (x,y,z) : z>0,y<x^2, x^2+y^2<1, x^2+y^2=z^2\}$$

You may check that $C=C_0\cup C_1$ is a convex set. But when adding the origin $x_0=(0,0,0)$ it is no longer star shaped at $x_0$. The reason being that there are line segments on the boundary arbitrarily close to $x_0$.

Comment: But why can you write $\{x_0\}\cup C_0\cup C_1$ as a union of finitely many closed convex sets? It does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It is the union of two convex sets: $C=C_0\cup C_1$ and $\{x_0\}$.

Comment: But the question says "finitely many *closed* convex sets".

Comment: Oups, overlooked that part. A finite union of closed convex sets is always locally star-shaped.